# REST Level 3 with HATEOAS - How to implement custom actions

Tags: rest, hateoas, spring-hateoas

I have a RESTful API with Spring HATEOAS. I try to stick to Level 3. And now I have a resource and operations that can be performed on it. One of them is related to **Profile** resource. Profiles can be **cloned**. And now I wonder how to do it properly. Clone operation already creates new profile. I was thinking about:

- `api/profile/{id}/clone` - POST. url contains id of the profile that should be cloned. Other required parameters are in request body
- `api/profile/clone` - POST. all information is in request body.

Which is better? Or maybe both are not proper ways of implementing this actions and other approach should be used?

Comment: If the URL contains a verb it's definitely not REST. Strip `/clone` from the second alternative, then you have it.

Comment: if I strip clone, how do I know that operation is cloning?

Comment: Because it has the appropriate media type.

Answer (score 0):

You can do POST request to api/profile/{id}/clone resource, is it absolutely right!

Just remember that POST operatios tend to be unsafed, and not imdepotent, what means that each new incoming request to your resource will create a new one...

http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/idempotency.html

Comment: _"is it absolutely right"_ Arguments, please. There is no right btw.

Comment: In that scenario, POST is the best option to create a "children" resource from profile, passing in the route of parent resource his ID...
Neither PUT on that URI nor the second proposed option does not fits in that case...

The clone operation will be made from an profile (parent resource), so the uri to that should be:
api/profile/{id}/clone - POST

Comment: The question is not about the method, but about the URL, in particular with regard to level 3 of the Richardson maturity model. If clone is used as a verb (and we can assume it is), then it's not RESTful. If it's used as a noun and you can post to it, then it must be a collection, but you cannot read from it, so it's not. So neither of the OP's approaches can be considered as RESTful according to Richardson's model.

Comment: I'm agree, is that i don't see clone as a verb, i see it as a noun...

And, i understood your point too, about my answer, independently of the discussion, i should write my point as a comment, to continue the discussion an not do it as an answer, and I had not seen your comments before, i am sorry and thank you too, i'm  starting to interact a little more with stackoverflow and not only searching for questions about my issues...and is it a learning process